# Usage of Cassandra 1.2 Vnodes in production

Tags: cassandra

One year passed since Vnodes was released with Cassandra 1.2. I have read a couple of Datastax articles describering this feature, they said the feature is awesome, but I want to ask those people who use it **in production**:

1. Is it really stable and ready to production?
2. What about Repair speed and disk usage overhead while Repair is running? Very important for us
3. What about rebalancing speed?
4. What about Hadoop stability/performance while using it with Cassandra vnodes enabled?
5. When should I avoid of using vnodes?
6. We have 1.5Tb per node with RF=3. When I turned vnodes on is all the data will be redistributed? My concern is network

Comment: That's 6 questions. You should post them separately. Also, they might be closed as off topic for being subjective.

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer all of your questions, but here's what I can help with.

1. Repair is only very slightly affected by vnodes.  Assuming you have 256 tokens per node, there are 256 times as many repair tasks with each one being 256 times smaller.  For anything other than a very small amount of data, the extra overhead in creating the extra tasks is negligible.  So I don't think you will notice any difference with repair with 1.5 TB of data.
2. You don't need to rebalance with vnodes.  When you add and remove nodes the cluster remains balanced.
3. Upgrading to vnodes is the biggest challenge.  Practically all data needs to be redistributed.  This can be done with shuffle (which in practice doesn't work very well so is not recommended), decommissioning and bootstrapping each node (which leaves one node temporarily storing a copy of all your data) or by duplicating your hardware and creating a new virtual data center and then decommissioning the old one.